# Keywords extraction for business rule text classification

Tags: classification, text, word

I would like to classify texts without using any ML model. My idea is to find a list of keywords that I would assign to each class. Then when I need to classify a new text, I can compare it with my list of keywords and count how many keywords for each class are in the text; the class with the most corresponding keywords would be my final prediction.

```
Example of classification for this list of keywords:

green : A
red : B
apple : A
car : C

The sentence "A green apple in a car" is classified as A.
(Points => A : 2, B : 0, C : 1)
```

The question is what are good techniques for me to explore in order to build my keyword list based on thousands of different text pieces and ~5 classes ? Most keywords algos I found (RAKE,...) are focused on extracting keywords from one text which is totally not my goal.

It would be a good 'baseline' algo for me to then compare results with more advanced ML classification techniques for my study.

Comment: A „one hot“ encoded bag of words, where you only use „frequent words“ applied to a multiclass logit with (strong) regularization will essentially lead to a list of keywords which are (most) relevant for detecting some class. You only need to look at the top features (aka words).

Answer (score 0):

You should probably consider a simple case of conditional probabilities - for example, a Naive Bayes Classifier. Assuming for example that you are using Python, you could look up an example of "Naive Bayes spam classifier" - in your example, you would need to rely on 5 cases, instead of the default 2 that spam engines rely on.
An example can be found here: https://www.kdnuggets.com/2020/07/spam-filter-python-naive-bayes-scratch.html

Answer (score 0):

Match your text with a list of keywords instead of the other way you normally think how to solve this by searching your keywords in text. Look for example how the Aho-Corasick algorithm works. You can use you classifications as output for the keywords found in text. Your solution can be keyword tree like AHO. You might not need the failure and goto transactions because you don't like to search for overlapping keywords